# How to adjust probability threhold in XGBoost classifier when using Scikit-Learn API

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, xgboost

I have a question about xgboost classifier with sklearn API. It seems it has a parameter to tell how much probability should be returned as True, but i can't find it.

Normally, `xgb.predict` would return boolean and `xgb.predict_proba` would return probability within  interval [0,1]. I think the result is related. There should be a probability threshold to decide sample's class.

```
dtrain, dtest = train_test_split(data, test_size=0.1, random_state=22)

param_dict={'base_score': 0.5,
 'booster': 'gbtree',
 'colsample_bylevel': 1,
 'colsample_bytree': 1,
 'gamma': 0,
 'learning_rate': 0.1,
 'max_delta_step': 0,
 'max_depth': 4,
 'min_child_weight': 6,
 'missing': None,
 'n_estimators': 1000,
 'objective': 'binary:logistic',
 'reg_alpha': 0,
 'reg_lambda': 1,
 'scale_pos_weight': 1,
 'subsample': 1}

xgb = XGBClassifier(**param_dict,n_jobs=2)

xgb.fit(dtrain[features], dtrain['target'])

result_boolean = xgb.predict(dtest[features])
print(np.sum(result_boolean))
Output:936

result_proba = xgb.predict_proba(dtest[features])
result_boolean2= (result_proba[:,1] > 0.5) 
print(np.sum(result_boolean2))
Output:936
```

It looks like the default probability threshold is 0.5, so the result array has same amount of True. But I can't find where to adjust it in the code.
`predict(data, output_margin=False, ntree_limit=None,  validate_features=True)` Also, I have tested `base_score`, but it didn't affect the result.

The main reason I want to change probability threshold is that I want to test `XGBClassifier` with different probability threshold by `GridSearchCV` method. `xgb.predict_proba` seems like it can't be merged into `GridSearchCV`.  How to change probability threshold in the `XGBClassifier`?

Comment: What exactly is the problem with predict_proba() and GridSearchCV ?

Comment: Sorry, I find that 'can't be merged into GridSearchCV' is quite misleading.For example,If i write
`grid = GridSearchCV(xb, param_grid, scoring='precision',fit_params=fit_params,cv=4)`
`grid.fit(X=dtrain[features],y=dtrain[target])`
And then I would get the best parameters based on the precision when the probability threshold is 0.5. But I want to change the probability threshold to 0.7 or 0.8.

Answer (score 2):

When you use ROC AUC (ROC=Receiver Operating Characteristic, AUC=Area Under Curve) as the scoring function, the gridsearch will be done with predict_proba(). The chosen classifier hyperparameter will be the one that has the best overall performance *across all possible decision thresholds*.

`GridSearchCV(scoring='roc_auc', ....)`

Then you can plot the ROC curve in order to determine the decision threshold that gives you the desired balance of precision vs. recall / true-positive vs. false-negative.

[image]

More info in [scikit-learn documentation on ROC](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#roc-metrics)

Comment: Thanks. I thnik ROC-AUC can be useful in my case. But is it possible to change the decision threshold of XGBClassifier, so i didn't need to use `predict_proba` and then set decision threshold by myself?

Comment: Is it me or this doesn't answer the question?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question!

Answer (score 2):

I think you should look at the source code to understand. I had troubles to find it, but I found as it works in lightgbm and I guess that xgboost should work similarly.

Go here (https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pythonapi/lightgbm.LGBMClassifier.html#lightgbm.LGBMClassifier.predict) and look at the method "predict":

```
def predict(self, X, raw_score=False, num_iteration=None,
            pred_leaf=False, pred_contrib=False, **kwargs):
    """Docstring is inherited from the LGBMModel."""
    result = self.predict_proba(X, raw_score, num_iteration,
                                pred_leaf, pred_contrib, **kwargs)
    if callable(self._objective) or raw_score or pred_leaf or pred_contrib:
        return result
    else:
        class_index = np.argmax(result, axis=1)
        return self._le.inverse_transform(class_index)


predict.__doc__ = LGBMModel.predict.__doc__
```

Practically the classifier is trained as a multi-class classifier every time and it chooses the class that has a higher probability.  The output of predict_proba is:

predicted_probability (array-like of shape = [n_samples, n_classes]) – The predicted probability for each class for each sample.

And you see that the method says:

```
class_index = np.argmax(result, axis=1)
```

Where "result" is the output of predict_proba.
Now, if you have predict_proba for many classes do they sum to 1? I guess so, but I suppose we should go into the classifier loss function to really understand what is going on...

this is what I would read next!
http://wiki.fast.ai/index.php/Log_Loss

Comment: Good info, but not an answer to question